# How to get the real position were a point is drawn after translate and rotate in P5JS

Tags: rotation, coordinates, p5.js, translate, get-transform

I read a lot, and tried many things, but can't get this done, and it seems simple

I have the following p5js code

```
function setup() {
  let canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  push();
  translate(50,100);
  point(25,25);
  // MISSING CODE to get 75,125
  pop();
  
}
```

And I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get the actual coordinates were the point is drawn,
I read about getTransform, the matrix, and a lot of stuff, but seems impossible to get it done. Also I need to use rotation in the transform, so that makes it even harder

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use variables, so you can keep track of how much you translated and the location of your point, so you can them add them to obtain the desired result.

```
let trans_x = 50
let trans_y = 100
let point_x = 25
let point_y = 25


translate(trans_x, trans_y);
point(point_x, point_y);

result_x = trans_x + point_x  // 50+25=75
result_y = trans_y + point_y  // 100+25=125
```

You could use Vectors so you don't have to define 2 variables, but you get the idea.

Usually you would call WorldPosition to the absolute position of the object and RelativePosition to the position the object relative to the CameraPosition

The translation would be called CameraPosition and to make your code more efficient you should only draw objects that their RelativePosition falls inside the drawable area.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that i Don't know how to keep track of rotations, I'm having a hard time with math

Comment: the way of keeping track is storing the rotation in a variable. a rotation doesn't modify the location of a point, so if you just want the position keep track of the translation, if you also want to keep track of the orientation of the object, save the rotation amount in a variable. In your question you have writtn an example and I provided a solution for that example

Comment: In principle it should be a matter of keeping track of your coordinate space (as a matrix) then applying this coordinate space (matrix vector multiplication) to convert between local / global coordinate systems. Processing has helper functions such as `modelX()/modelY()/modelZ()` , `screenX()/screenY()` as well as `PMatrix2D`/`PMatrix3D` classes. p5.js doesn't have that yet, but you can find useful info in this [github issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/4743). I wish it was simpler than this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some transformation matrix magic:

```
  const ctx = drawingContext; // Alias for this._renderer.drawingContext
  const matrix = ctx.getTransform(); // This is a DOMMatrix in web browsers that support it
  // for the 2D case:
  const rot = atan2(matrix.b, matrix.a);
  console.log(rot); // the answer is in Radians if I am not mistaken
  const scale_x = sqrt(matrix.a**2 + matrix.c**2);
  const scale_y = sqrt(matrix.b**2 + matrix.d**2);
  const pos = createVector(matrix.e/scale_x, matrix.f/scale_y); // check pos.x and pos.y
  console.log(pos);
```